# apache 2.4.25 Cipher Strength issue

Tags: ssl, encryption, apache2

I use Debian 8 and apache 2.4.25 from testing. I get a A+ from SSL labs. All field at 100% except Cipher Strength.

I tried lot of settings but my Cipher still contain "128", for example :  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)

I change Cipher into my ssl vhost conf and etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf How can I use only the strongest cipger suite ?

Now my settings are : SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS

Answer (score 0):

Appending !SHA1 will knock out the weakest ones you have left.  If you wanted to be more surgical, you could append !AES128-SHA and follow the pattern from 'man ciphers' if something else stands out at you.

Comment: I would like to remove all 128. Currently I have : SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH ; Unfortunately when I check on SSL lab I can see 128 cipher ....